# Zend Framework : Invalid contrller specified (error) ??? Help

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I moved my project from windows to ubuntu and had this error while trying to run the project:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with 
message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in
/home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#1 /home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97):
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#2 /home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/library/Zend/Application.php(366):
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() 
#3 /home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/index.php(56): 
Zend_Application->run() 
#4 {main} thrown in
/home/truong/webdev/qtcmsv2/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php 
on line 248
```

I did have ErrorController.php file in my default module :

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    /**
    * This action handles
    * - Application errors
    * - Errors in the controller chain arising from missing
    * controller classes and/or action methods
    */
    public function errorAction()
    {
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');
    switch ($errors->type) {
    case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
    case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
    // 404 error -- controller or action not found
    $this->getResponse()->setRawHeader('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    $this->view->title = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found';
    break;
    default:
    // application error; display error page, but don't change
    // status code
    $this->view->title = 'Application Error';
    break;
    }

    $this->view->message = $errors->exception;
    }

}
```

My project ran very smoothly in Windows, but the error above always occurs when running in Ubuntu.
How can I solve this problem?? Please help me!
ps : Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I have the same problem an realize I mistype the error controller as **ErrorControler** .php, so I chaged to **ErrorController** .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means ZF can't find the error controller so it could be that something is not where it belongs, something is configured incorrectly (like a path), is misnamed, permissions are off, etc. Hard to tell from the info you provided as the error could be in index.php, your bootstrap, config, etc.